# pd.apply(pd.Series.interpolate) with more arguments

Tags: python, pandas

How do I rewrite

```
df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
```

so it can achieve the same functionality as

```
df.interpolate(method='nearest')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an argument to [`apply`](http://www.jeffreytratner.com/example-pandas-docs/html-minor-doc-fixup-10-25/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate, args=('nearest',))
```

or

```
df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate, method='nearest')
```

Comment: Anton,why there is a "," after 'nearest' in args()

Comment: @kevinL to make it tuple, if you'll pass `('nearest')` it will interpret as 7 arguments because it'll try to split that string. Actually you could try both ways and you'll see. `type(('a'))` and `type(('a',))` will give `str` and `tuple` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a function, and pick the axis (0 for columns):

```
df.apply(lambda a: a.interpolate(method='nearest'), axis=0)
```